# Downloading large videos gives memory warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, download, filesystems

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    if(data != nil){
       //open output stream
        NSOutputStream *stream=[[NSOutputStream alloc] initToFileAtPath:_filePath append:YES];
        [stream open];
        NSString *str=(NSString *)data;

        //write to file
        NSUInteger left = [str length];
        NSUInteger bytesWritten = 0;
        do {
            bytesWritten = [stream write:[data bytes] maxLength:left];
            downloadedData = downloadedData + bytesWritten;
            if (-1 == bytesWritten) break;
            left -= bytesWritten;

        } while (left > 0);

        if (left) {
            NSLog(@"stream error: %@", [stream streamError]);
            [self handleForCurreptedDownloading];
        }
        [stream close];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"data nil");
    }
}
```

Tried with this code also but not working as it is giving same memory warning

```
downloadedData += [data length];

        NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:_filePath];
        [fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
        [fileHandle writeData:data];
        [fileHandle closeFile];
```

This is the code i have used with fileSystem i am directly writing and appending into file. I have also used ARC. Still it is giving memory warning and getting crashed when i try to download large video files.

I have also checked before downloading the disk space

```
+ (NSNumber *)getFreeSpace
{
//    float freeSpace = 0.0f;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[paths lastObject] error: &error];
    NSNumber *fileSystemFreeSizeInBytes = 0;
    if (dictionary) {
        fileSystemFreeSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemFreeSize];
//        freeSpace = [fileSystemFreeSizeInBytes floatValue];
    } else {
        //Handle error
    }  
    return fileSystemFreeSizeInBytes;
}
```

I have checked with allocations and it is giving me the stable graph.
Is there any other way to download and manage large video files?

Comment: whats the size of your video file? coz i have downloaded zip files upto 150MB without any problem. if possible give me the url of video

Comment: I am trying to download video of size 400MB. and i have to download without size bound until my disk size is full.

Comment: then there is only one option download your video in packets of 100 mb and then create one single packet of all. thats feasible solution

Comment: Is there any reference for how to do that? i mean download in packets of 100mb?

Comment: yeh sure ,just wait for while, let me check one thing

Comment: from where r u downloading the video file? can i have access to that link?

Comment: Downloading youtube video

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28368/discussion-between-dipen-panchasara-and-roshni)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the complete downloaded file data in the didReceiveData function - which probably is HUGE.

I would use a framework like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking) for your download needs, it makes things a lot simpler.

For example, for downloading large files without getting the whole data at once and then write it to a file, use a NSOutputStream to write parts of the file while they are downloaded.

This is from the [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ) documentation:

```
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:@"download.zip" append:NO];
```

Comment: Please check my question.I have added the code which is using NSOutputStream

Comment: Try the framework - there should be no problem downloading large files with it, I just did so for 150MB + files without any problem. You can also try to not write the data to a file for testing  - do you still get a memory problem?

Comment: Is it wrong if i write chunk of data i get in `didReceiveData` and append it to file?

Comment: No, but apparently you do have a problem with the memory - so you should try to find out where exactly the problem is by ruling out some things.